# How to order by mulitiple relations sum count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing with Rails 3.2.8 and want to order a model by sum of multiple relations count.

There's a Doc model which has many subcatrels and subinsrels, and both are Relation model(not a model relation, a model named 'Relation').

***doc.rb***

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :denotations
  has_many :instances, :through => :denotations
  has_many :subcatrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :through => :denotations, :source => :subrels
  has_many :subinsrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :through => :instances, :source => :subrels
  scope :pmdocs, where(:sourcedb => 'PubMed')
  .
  .
end
```

I want to order Doc model by sum of count subcatrels and subinsrels.

I've tried below to order scope pmdocs.

```
Doc.pmdocs.includes([:subcatrels, :subinsrels]).group('docs.id').order('(count(subcatrels.id) + count(subinsrels.id)) DESC')
```

and got an error below.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subcatrels"
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "docs".id, (count(subcatrels.id) + count(su...

: SELECT  DISTINCT "docs".id, (count(subcatrels.id) + count(subinsrels.id)) AS alias_0 FROM "docs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "denotations" ON "denotations"."doc_id" = "docs"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "relations" ON "relations"."subj_id" = "denotations"."id" AND "relations"."subj_type" = 'Denotation' LEFT OUTER JOIN "denotations" "denotations_docs_join" ON "denotations_docs_join"."doc_id" = "docs"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "instances" ON "instances"."obj_id" = "denotations_docs_join"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "relations" "subinsrels_docs" ON "subinsrels_docs"."subj_id" = "instances"."id" AND "subinsrels_docs"."subj_type" = 'Instance' WHERE "docs"."sourcedb" = 'PubMed' GROUP BY docs.id ORDER BY (count(subcatrels.id) + count(subinsrels.id)) DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

How to order Doc model by sum of count subcatrels and subinsrels?

The other models source codes are below.

***denotation.rb***

```
class Denotation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doc
  has_many :instances, :foreign_key => "obj_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :as => :subj, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :objrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :as => :obj, :dependent => :destroy
  .
  .
end
```

**instance.rb**

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :obj, :class_name => 'Denotation'
  has_many :subrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :as => :subj, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :objrels, :class_name => 'Relation', :as => :obj, :dependent => :destroy
  .
  .
end
```

**Associations image**
[image]

Comment: Can you add FULL query generated by Rails?

Comment: I've added full SQL query at error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask for `subinsrels.id` in `WHERE` if it's not a table name!

Comment: I guess so, and have to write raw SQL like join, select and count. However I have no idea to join multiple relations which does not has same relations always.

Comment: @MAsuda sorry but your associations are so complicated that unless you make a visual of them (entity relationship graph) I'm unable to dig through this.

Comment: I've added associations image, so please refer to it.